# PHP: PEAR mail message error

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I can send an email by the code in this (url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

but the errors shown as following...

> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 450
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 467
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 474
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 517
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 521
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 376
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 628
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 809
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 813
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 821
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 825
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 829
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 834
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 656
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 249
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 285
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 952
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 955
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Mail.php on line 253
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 982
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 985
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1063
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1066
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1126
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1136
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1141
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 491
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 265
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 494
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/abc/pear/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 497
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/p/testEmail.php on line 27

Message successfully sent!

in php.ini file, I also change error reporting level to

"error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT"

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you're telling PHP to show all errors and strict standard infractions.  To ignore the Strict Standards (which are non fatal) change your error reporting level to

```
 // PHP.INI
 error_reporting=E_ERROR^E_PARSE

 //or better, inline with error_reporting()
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

The root of the error is PEAR's Mail Class definition.  I'm using a Mac Server also and PEAR.  It is the better solution for multiple emails, however, it will raise Strict Standard errors.  You can ignore.

You probably have this line of code after your send() call.

```
 if (PEAR::isError($mail_object)) {print($mail_object->getMessage());}
```

I prefer taking this line out and instead using try/catch/exception instead.

I would change your error reporting level with one of the error reporting modifications to your PHP.INI file or inline (best option).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a cPanel server, go into your PEAR packages and make sure that you've updated your Net Server and SMTP packages.  You should install net_socket2 and net_smtp2 packages.  This solved my problem with this issue after upgrading to PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. Check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248503/non-static-method-peariserror-should-not-be-called-statically?r=SearchResults&s=1|114.7471](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248503/non-static-method-peariserror-should-not-be-called-statically?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C114.7471)

You can use `(new PEAR)->isError($variable)` or `is_a($obj, 'PEAR_Error')` but you had better upgrade your code and use more modern libraries.