# Probleme when Adding Host in centreon 2.5

Tags: php, monitoring, pear, hosts

I have to add host in centreon 2.5.

I first go to configuration > hosts > add, and I fill in the infos about the host and then I save.
Then i go to the host home, and I found nothing.

I searched ont the web and I found that there is a little problem of compatibility with centreon 2.5 and php 5.4 with module PEAR.

my /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Fri Apr 03 09:27:18.004435 2015] [:error] [pid 10146] [client 10.130.5.6:55537] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/local/centreon/www/class/centreonDB.class.php on line 305
[Fri Apr 03 09:27:18.004629 2015] [:error] [pid 10146] [client 10.130.5.6:55537] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/local/centreon/www/class/centreonDB.class.php on line 305
[Fri Apr 03 09:27:18.004928 2015] [:error] [pid 10146] [client 10.130.5.6:55537] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/local/centreon/www/class/centreonDB.class.php on line 305
```

So, the problem is PEAR::isError().
I don't now how to fix it.

Edit : the problem was the incompatibilty beetwen PHP 5.4 and centreon 2.5, so i downloaded CES 3.1 instead of installing in centreon manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248503/non-static-method-peariserror-should-not-be-called-statically)